# Stroke for Custom Image in Fabric JS

Tags: fabricjs, stroke

I'm trying to create stroke around images I've added to canvas using Fabric JS. The stroke I've added to a PNG with transparent background looked like this:

[image]

Although I'm trying to create stroke "around" the image and stick the stroke to the edges of the image, Fabric JS just creates a "square" stroke.

How can I accomplish stroke "around" the image, any thoughts?
I can't seem to find any documentation or demo to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Thank you

Comment: You can use svg instead of png if you want to change or add stroke width, it will be easy.

Comment: Can you please share your code i can help you

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in few steps.

1. Upload png image to Canvas
2. add "sticker stroke effect" (from [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20190410091350/http://artplustech.com/sticker-effect-on-transparent-pngs-with-html5-canvas/))

```js
      // this._ctx = context of canvas
      this._ctx.shadowColor = '#fff';
      this._ctx.shadowBlur = 3;
      this._ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
      this._ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;
      this._ctx.drawImage(img, 30, 30, img.width, img.height);

      // get contents of blurry bordered image
      const imgData = this._ctx.getImageData(
        0,
        0,
        this._ctx.canvas.width - 1,
        this._ctx.canvas.height - 1
      );

      const opaqueAlpha = 255;

      // turn all non-transparent pixels to full opacity
      for (let i = imgData.data.length; i > 0; i -= 4) {
        if (imgData.data[i + 3] > 0) {
          imgData.data[i + 3] = opaqueAlpha;
        }
      }

      // write transformed opaque pixels back to image
      this._ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);

      this._ctx.shadowColor = '#aaa';
      this._ctx.shadowBlur = 3;
      this._ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
      this._ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;
      this._ctx.drawImage(this._canvas, 0, 0);
```

3. Export data to base64 and paste it through fabric

```js
      // you can export your image to data url
      const url = this._canvas.toDataURL();

      // and you can add image from data url to fabric
      fabric.Image.fromURL(url, oImg => {
        this._cf.add(oImg);
      });
```

It will work, but for better user experience you should think, how you will do it dynamically (I'm working on it right now), I mean: user add an image, you want to give him option to "stroke" or not and blah-blah..